# How to make this sql query compatible for older verisons of mysql such v.5.5 and above?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query it works on MySQL 8.0 but not on the below versions like MySQL 5.5. How to make this compatible as I am getting this error on web server:  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by pid order by age' at line 11

```
SELECT p.id,  p.pid, p.name, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.dr = 1 THEN t.name END) as name1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.dr = 1 THEN age END) as age1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.dr = 2 THEN t.name END) as name2,
         MAX(CASE WHEN t.dr = 2 THEN t.age END) as age2,
            MAX(CASE WHEN t.dr = 3 THEN t.name END) as name3,
         MAX(CASE WHEN t.dr = 3 THEN t.age END) as age3,
             MAX(CASE WHEN t.dr = 4 THEN t.name END) as name4,
         MAX(CASE WHEN t.dr = 4 THEN t.age END) as age4
FROM Table1 p
join (select id , pid, name, age,  DENSE_RANK() OVER (partition by pid order by age) as dr
from Table2) t on p.pid= t.pid
group by p.id, p.pid, p.name
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d324e7654218dae3d1168df2bf529099

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 select version();
```

| version() |
| --- |
| 5.5.62 |

Schema:

```
 CREATE TABLE Table1
     (id int , name varchar(15) , pid int   )

 INSERT INTO Table1
  values   (1, 'Jack', 1521), 
  (2, 'Steve',1522)

 CREATE TABLE Table2
     (id  int, pid int, name varchar(15), age int);
 
 INSERT INTO Table2
    
 VALUES
     (1, 1521, 'John', 12),
     (2, 1521, 'Maria', 7),
     (3, 1521, 'Larry', 3),
     (4, 1522, 'Harry', 5)
```

Query:

```
 SELECT p.id,  p.pid, p.name, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN t.dr = 1 THEN t.name END) as name1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN t.dr = 1 THEN age END) as age1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN t.dr = 2 THEN t.name END) as name2,
          MAX(CASE WHEN t.dr = 2 THEN t.age END) as age2,
             MAX(CASE WHEN t.dr = 3 THEN t.name END) as name3,
          MAX(CASE WHEN t.dr = 3 THEN t.age END) as age3,
              MAX(CASE WHEN t.dr = 4 THEN t.name END) as name4,
          MAX(CASE WHEN t.dr = 4 THEN t.age END) as age4
 FROM Table1 p
 join (select id , pid, name, age,  (select count(*) from Table2 t2
 where  t.pid=t2.pid and t2.age<=t.age) as dr
 from Table2 t) t on p.pid= t.pid
 group by p.id, p.pid, p.name
```

Output:

| id | pid | name | name1 | age1 | name2 | age2 | name3 | age3 | name4 | age4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1521 | Jack | Larry | 3 | Maria | 7 | John | 12 | *null* | *null* |
| 2 | 1522 | Steve | Harry | 5 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=6560298ae9c326600c7cfa4660de928e)*

Answer (score 1):

One method is a correlated subquery to replace `DENSE_RANK()`:

```
FROM Table1 p JOIN
     (SELECT t2.*,
             (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tt2.age)
              FROM table2 tt2
              WHERE tt2.pid = t2.pid AND
                    tt2.age <= t2.age
             ) as dr
      FROM Table2 t2
     ) t 
     ON p.pid = t.pid
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eed41284bd20d6afd6acbeb7d8e1da5f) is a db<>fiddle.